# Move a marker smoothly between two lat-long values in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to move a marker from one point to another in Openlayers 3. I have used the following code and it works fine. But the problem is that the movement is not smooth.

```
iconGeometry.setCoordinates((new ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')));
```

Any idea to make the movement smooth ???

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/feature-move-animation.html). Is it smooth enough?

Some things to note:

1. You will need **a lot** of coordinates between the two points (if you don't have them, use [Arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js) to do this).
2. Then you will use [`postcompose`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.render.Event.html#event:postcompose) to [draw](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.render.canvas.Immediate.html#drawFeature) a Point (`ol.Feature(ol.geom.Point)`) at each coordinate.
3. The trick to control the speed is to jump (or not) some indexes in your long array of coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I saw this example. But in my application the lat-long values are coming from a vehichle with a GPS device on it. And the interval between getting next point is upto 1 to 10 seconds. So what i need is to move the marker between these two points smoothly. The above cod ecould not help me doing this..

Comment: As Jonatas Walker said, if we need **a lot** of points, can any one tell me how to get those if I am using GeoServer to display roads using PostGIS via WMS